# Get raw type inside std::reference_wrapper in type trait

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, type-traits

### Problem

I have a custom vector type for math operations. I can give it a type directly

```
MyVector<2, int>vec{4,5};
```

or a reference_wrapper

```
int num1 = 4;
int num2 = 5;
MyVector<2, std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec2{std::ref(num1), std::ref(num2)};
```

which both works.

However, i'd like to restrict the `MyVector` class to only take arithmetic types. Thought about putting a static_assert inside the class like this:

```
static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "Vector type T must be an arithmetic");
```

but of course this fails for `reference_wrapper<int>`.

### Question

How can i "unwrap" an std::reference_wrapper to get the underlying type and use it in a type trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try:

```
template <typename T>
struct unwrap_ref 
{
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T>
struct unwrap_ref<std::reference_wrapper<T>> 
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using unwrap_ref_type = typename unwrap_ref<T>::type;
```

And use `static_assert(std::is_arythmetic_type_v<unwrap_ref_type<T>>);`

Comment: works great, thanks! one note though: i replaced your `std::reference_type` with `std::reference_wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

You might use `std::conditional_t` and `std::reference_wrapper<T>::type`:

```
// Helper
template <typename T> struct is_reference_wrapper : std::false_type{};
template <typename T> struct is_reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>> : std::true_type{};
```

And then

```
static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<
                  typename std::conditional_t<
                      is_reference_wrapper<T>::value,
                      T,
                      std::type_identity<T>
                  >::type // Notice the extra type (in addition to _t)
              >,
              "Vector type T must be an arithmetic");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24932173a27d4070)

Note: Types provided in `std::conditional` are "evaluated", so you can't do

```
std::conditional_t<is_reference_wrapper<T>::value,
                   typename T::type, // Hard error for types without `type` typename
                   T
                  >
```

so we delay that evaluation outside (both types should have `::type`, and C++20 `std::type_identity` has one :) )